# Akka server stops immediately after running

Tags: scala, akka, grpc

I'm trying to set up a simple akka-grpc server as it's done in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/walkthrough.html#running-the-server).

```
migrationResult match {
  case Left(exception) => system.log.error(exception, "Exception while migrating schema", exception)
  case Right(_) =>
    system.log.info(s"Schema migrated with success")
    val registerService: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] =
      RegisterServiceHandler(new RegisterImpl())

      Http().newServerAt(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = port).bind(registerService)
```

}

Problem is that it stops immediately after running, it does not listen for any call.
The service implementation (`RegisterImpl`) looks like this

```
class RegisterImpl(implicit mat: Materializer) extends RegisterService with LazyLogging {
  import mat.executionContext
  override def registerUser(request: RegisterRequest): Future[RegisterResponse] = {
    val credentials = UserCredentials(UUID.randomUUID(), request.username, request.emailAddress, request.password)
    val user = User(None, request.fullName, request.city, request.address, request.neighborhood, credentials)

    val responseIO = for {
      _ <- userRepository.insertUser(user)
    } yield ()

    responseIO.attempt.unsafeRunSync() match {
      case Right(_) =>
        Future.successful(new RegisterResponse(true))
      case Left(e) =>
        logger.error(s"User registration failed because of error: ${e.getMessage}")
        Future.successful(new RegisterResponse(false))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you run things synchronously (it is blocking!) rather than using `unsafeToFuture`? It would be my first suspect.

Answer (score 2):

I am suspecting that your blocking code (using `runUnsafeSync`, mapping `Either` to `Future` synchronously) is to blame for it.

```
// This is blocking current thread
responseIO.attempt.unsafeRunSync() match {
  // These 2 create Futures, but only after blocking is released
  // by the finished IO computation (if it finishes...)
  case Right(_) =>
    Future.successful(new RegisterResponse(true))
  case Left(e) =>
    logger.error(s"User registration failed because of error: ${e.getMessage}")
    Future.successful(new RegisterResponse(false))
}
// You'd have to use
//   Future { blocking { ... } }
// instead of match + Future.successful to be async
// (and inform Future's thread pool that you are blocking)
// (but it still could lead to a deadlock or worse performance).
```

There would be several ways to deal with it (using `Future { ... }` with [`blocking`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/concurrent/index.html#blocking%5BT%5D(body:=%3ET):T), debugging thread pools), but I would suggest implementing your service as:

```
responseIO.attempt.map {
  case Right(_) =>
    new RegisterResponse(true)
  case Left(e) =>
    logger.error(s"User registration failed because of error: ${e.getMessage}")
    new RegisterResponse(false)
}.unsafeToFuture // IO knows how to create a Future without issues
```

to make sure that conversion to `Future` is handled by `IO` itself without needless blocking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was related to sbt and not to akka or implementation, I've just changed sbt version from build.properties from `1.6.1` to `1.5.2`, still not sure what went wrong with the newer version

Comment: I had 1.6.2 and it worked one month ago, but today I had the same issue. when downgraded sbt works again. Strange

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed concerned with the insides of the sbt. A simple workaround is to add a line

```
fork := true
```

in `build.sbt` file.

See this discussion for more information: https://github.com/akka/akka-grpc/issues/1536#issuecomment-1004155584

Comment: Such an undervalued response